# In Graphite can you use different aggregation functions for different resolutions of the same metric?

Tags: graph, graphite-carbon

I'd like the finest resolution be aggregated with `max`, while the next resolution be aggregated with `sum`.

Can this be done for a given metric?

Comment: Apparently impossible due to the underlying Whisper database having a single aggregation type for all archives.